# layout input elements inside div vertically with equal spacing, without using table element

Tags: html, css

How to layout **input** elements vertically so that the space b/w the elements are equal and without using **table** element. When the viewport height changes the layout should resize.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/agfw7731/ with the following code.

```
<div id="login_container">
    <input id="signup_username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
    <input id="signup_password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="signup_retype_password" type="password" placeholder="ReType Password">
</div>
```

Comment: where is your css code?

Comment: You should look http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @Core972 Dont want to use flexbox as it is not yet standardised.

Comment: @lolka_bolka My css code does not work, Hence i did not pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this http://jsfiddle.net/agfw7731/5/

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#login_container{
    width: 100%;        
    max-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#login_container input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: But the input elements are not equally spaced

Comment: Explain what you mean with _"are not equally spaced"_

Comment: * The expected output is when there are 3 input elements in a div, each div must be seperated by a distance of 33.33% of the height, instead the elements are grouped at the center with a fixed hardcoded spacing in between.